# Storing a .csv file for sorting c++

Tags: c++, csv, struct

I have .csv file with 502 lines and i want to organize them so that i can later sort them by duration,weekday,etc. I thought the best way to do this is creating sruct for each attribute but i dont know how to assign each attribute to the struct. Help pls

````
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct classesstruct{
    string cadeira;
    string uccode;
    string weekday;
    int starthour;
    int duration;
    string type;
};


int main() {
    classesstruct Classes[502];
   ifstream myFile;
   myFile.open("C:/Users/utilizador/TrabalhoAED/classes.csv");

   while(myFile.good()) {
       string line;
       getline(myFile, line);
  
       
       
   }}```
````

Comment: Separate the sorting part from the reading. For the reading part search here. There are dozens of how to read a csv file in c++ questions.

Comment: `while(myFile.good()) {` read about this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: Start with the 2 duplicates for this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067179/how-can-i-read-from-csv-file-to-a-class-in-c-into-either-arrays-or-public-clas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66067179/how-can-i-read-from-csv-file-to-a-class-in-c-into-either-arrays-or-public-clas)

Comment: drescherjm makes a good point about the loop condition, but to be clear, it's not the check of `.good()` that is the problem.  It's the order of calling `.good()` and `getline()` that is the problem.   `while (string line; getline(myFile, line).good())` is perfectly ok, if a bit unnecessarily wordy (the contextual cast of a stream to `bool` will implcitly call `good()`, so you can also write `while (string line; getline(myFile, line))` )

Comment: i don't think C++ is the best tool for this for many reasons, you have a few things to learn before you are able to do this, like fstreams, lambda functions, stl functions, and a month or so of learning about C++ overall, if you are coding for simple things like reading and writing files, then you should use a higher level language, like python or java or C#

Comment: @AhmedAEK: For this particular job, PERL is better than any of those.  But often the need is to learn a tool (C++) and the task is a practical way of forcing oneself to learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

struct classesStruct{
    string ClassCode;
    string UcCode;
    string Weekday;
    int StartHour;
    int Duration;
    string Type;
};


int main() {
    vector<classesStruct> ArrClasses;
    classesStruct classe;
   ifstream myFile;
   myFile.open("C:/Users/utilizador/TrabalhoAED/classes.csv");
    string line="";
    getline(myFile,line);
    string tempString;
   while(getline(myFile,line)) {
        stringstream inputString(line);
        getline(inputString, classe.ClassCode, ',');
       getline(inputString, classe.UcCode, ',');
       getline(inputString, classe.Weekday, ',');

       getline(inputString, tempString, ',');
       classe.StartHour=atoi(tempString.c_str());

       tempString="";
       getline(inputString, tempString, ',');
       classe.Duration=atoi(tempString.c_str());

       getline(inputString,classe.Type,',');

       ArrClasses.push_back(classe);

       line = "";
   }
   for (auto x:ArrClasses){
       cout << x.UcCode << endl;

   }}
```

solved it, thank u all for the help

Comment: Note: You still have a potential hole: You've guarded the case where for any reason you don't get a line, but you have not protected yourself against the data on the line not being exactly what you expect. For example an empty line at the end of the file will result in the `getline`s reading from `inputString` quietly failing and bogus values being used.